# Highcharts - Change color of bar after setData finished with its animation?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

how can I switch the color of a barchart after the animation finished?

I have a barchart in highcharts, where I set some new data in the first and only series via `setData()`, working fine. The chart has an animation duration of 1000ms. Now I additionally want to change the color of the bar if the new data value exceeds 10. My approach is as follows:

```
 var x = 10
 chart = $('#id_of_my_chart').highcharts();
 chart.series[0].setData([ x ]);

 if (x > 7) {
    chart.series.update({ color: 'red' })
  }
```

The problem is that `update()` and `setData()` are executed simultaneously, what follows is that the update statement `series.update()` kicks in before the 1000ms animation of `setData()` are finished and thus breaks the animation.

My goal is to have the color change after the animation.

I am aware of the highchart functionality `event: { afterAnimate: {} } }` but could not really get this to work.

Has anybody achieved this?

Comment: Hi. I am a little bit confused, when do you want to change your data and your series color. Can you put your code onto jsFiddle and one more time explain precisely, what exactly do you want to achieve? I prepared jsFiddle for you already: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a1gq8fk5/

Comment: The simple solution would be to put your update call in a [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function.

Comment: Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/4hrvsdnL/